# Angular 14 inject() in Unit Test without TestBed

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

code below

When I run the unit test I get the error - inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.

There's plenty of help for this error if you use the TestBed, but we don't.

I'm using Angular 14.2.4 and it is a field initializer so I don't get it?

TypeScript file

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  ...

  private _componentRegistryService = inject(ComponentRegistryService);
```

spec file

```
fdescribe('DynamicComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let router: Router;

  const _componentRegistryService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ComponentRegistryService', ['getComponentsByRoute']);
  const _dynamicLoaderService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DynamicLoaderService', ['getUserComponentChoices']);

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = new MyComponent(router);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: You have to use the Angular TestBed because the inject comes from the Angular ecosystem and only will be initialized correctly in the TestBed

Answer (score 0):

You have to use TestBed. It's rather simple to do and doesn't add any appreciable overhead.

```
component = TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => new MyComponent(router));
```

That should be all you need to do.